# Ubuntu and Windows

Tags: 14.04, windows-7, hadoop

Currently I am working in Ubuntu. Big Data. I do not have Windows OS in my system. i am going to install hadoop in Ubuntu. But I don't know whether windows is compulsory to have along with ubuntu. Can anyone tell me if I can proceed with hadoop without having Windows with me, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

No, Hadoop is supported on those platforms, but there is no inherent requirement to run both in order to support Hadoop.

The documentation [Hadoop: Setting up a Single Node Cluster](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-common/SingleCluster.html#Prerequisites) has the instructions for installing on Linux such as the requirements:

- java
- ssh
- rsync

Nowhere on the Linux instructions, does it list Windows as a must-have. Windows is only mentioned as a separate link for those who wish to use the Windows version of Hadoop.